# Automated Robot test on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, robotframework

When I want to run my tests on Jenkins I can define which workflow I want.

When committing my test to gitlab i define a commit message, and to that message I add this :

```
 runTest=testsuites/someFolder/someWorkflow.robot
```

What I am wondering is if it is possible to select a certain test from that workflow to execute ? Currently all of test from it will run, and it takes a lot time.

Comment: I tend to just make a "SandBox" file which has the setup, tear down and the new stuff I will add to the "Main test file" once the new stuff works the way I want it to. Once It works the way intended, I add it at the bottom of the main file and test the main file to see if everything is fine. Bit cumbersome but yeah - Works for me!

Comment: Not really a solution for me since I would need to commit minimum 2 times, and each time I commit build starts automatically.

Comment: have you tried using tags and the "--include tag" option or the "--test testNamePattern" option?

Comment: Have not tried it. You have any example I could look at ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Robot user guide for selecting suites and testcases based on names,tags and patterns:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#selecting-test-cases

Options --suites and --tests are those which you could use.

If you are uncertain, create simple suite with multiple tests and execute it from favorite IDE (RED,RIDE,PyCharm) to check the command and parameters.

Comment: This helped. And IDE is IntelliJ :)